# SQL, update un column from query result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query:

```
select
    up.profile_id,
    uf.id
from
    uploads_files uf
inner join users u on
    u.id = uf.user_id
inner join user_profiles up on
    up.user_id = u.id;
```

It returns this table:

```
profile_id|id
---------------
165       |1632
123       |1436
...etc
```

I need to use that data an update this other table called "uploads_files"

```
id|user_id|filename|...etc..|profile_id
```

Right now `profile_id` is blank, so I want to update those `profile_id` where `id` matches with my previous result. How can I do it?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this to an `update` with this syntax.  From what you describe:

```
update uploads_files uf
    set uf.profile_id = up.profile_id
from users u join
     user_profiles up
     on up.user_id = u.id
where u.id = uf.user_id and uf.profile_id is null;
```

Comment: Cool, I was writing this one: `update uploads_files
    set profile_id = t1.profile_id
    from (select
  up.profile_id,
  uf.id
 from
  uploads_files uf
 inner join users u on
  u.id = uf.user_id
 inner join user_profiles up on
  up.user_id = u.id
         ) t1
    where uploads_files.user_id = t1.user_id`